# Using "level" after a long phrase

Tags: phrase-usage

I wrote this sentence:

> While, in the extraction algorithm, they may consider context before classifying an element, the contextual information are not explicitly specified **at the rules level (or even at the extraction rules level)**.

I supposed two levels for this program, the algorithm, and some rules which are input to the algorithm, then used "at the rules level". Am I correct at this? (By the way, `correct` takes `at` preposition, doesn't it?)

Comment: Just a note: "information" is singular, so "*the contextual information **is** not explicitly...*"

Comment: Are rules algorithms? Or is there another algorithm that processes the rules?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider *rule level* as a noun phrase. Levels usually are not singular, same as you might write in a company:

> That policy will be decided **at the management level**. (not *managements*).

Otherwise, your example makes sense, but I have to make an assumption that *contextual information* is multiple items, otherwise use *is* not *are*.

> While, in the extraction algorithm, they may consider context before classifying an element, the contextual information are not explicitly specified **at the rule level** (or even **at the extraction rule level**).